# Javascript GET redirect URL

Tags: javascript, ajax, get

I need to make a GET call to an API endpoint that returns a redirect, I have exposed the Location using CORS but can't find any method using Ajax nor Fetch to just get the Redirect URL. If anybody could help me out that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the fetch spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#atomic-http-redirect-handling):

> Redirects (a response whose status or internal response’s (if any) status is a redirect status) are not exposed to APIs. Exposing redirects might leak information not otherwise available through a cross-site scripting attack.

So it can't be done using browser-side JavaScript.